# Connection Information for Oracle SQL Developer database

Tags: oracle11g

I'm new to Oracle, and I have installed Oracle Database 11g.

When I open some connection on Oracle SQL Developer, I get a dialog where I've to enter the username and the password as the following :

[image]

The problem is that I don't knwo what is the username and the password, in the installation I choosed orcl as the Username and orcl as the password but when I enter them I get the error message :

[image]

How can I solve this problem ?

I've another question : what is this page `https://localhost:1158/em` and why I get  `Page Web Inaccessible` when I acces to it.

## EDIT 1 :

This is the content of the `listener.ora` file :

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\Aimad\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\Aimad\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\Aimad\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\app\Aimad
```

## EDIT 2:

this is the output of the command `tnsping xe` :

[image]

Comment: Which version of SQL Developer are you using?

Comment: @Polppan I use the version 1.5.5.59.69

Comment: See my answer below and if you are unable to get that window when you right click connection, I suggest you download one of the latest versions of SQL Developer from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting the error is because you have not specified service name or SID as it doesn't know to which instance it should connect.

I suppose you are using one of the latest versions of SQL Developer available for download.

Right click connections and choose New Connection from context menu, you will get a window like one is pasted below, there you enter connection details and do not forget to enter either service name or SID.

Hope this helps.
[image]

Comment: I did the same but I still get the same problem, I googled about it and  I found that it could be from the listener.ora file, please check the modification I made to my post to see the content of that file.

Comment: @SuSha Can you confirm that database listener is up and running? Besides try to connect to your schema from sqlplus.

Comment: @SuSha This will give an idea on how to check listener status http://www.brainsurface.com/blogsurface/how-to-check-status-of-oracle-database-listener/

Comment: @SuSha And from command prompt do as `tnsping <your service id>`

Comment: please check the modification I made to my post to see the output of that command.

Comment: Try what is mentioned in http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_tns_03505_failed_to_resolve_name.htm